# Nexus Mark Oracle Maven Repository as Invalid

Tags: nexus, sonatype

Creating a Proxy repository on Nexus that proxies Oracle Maven Repo (http://download.oracle.com/maven/) marks the Oracle Repo as "Attempting to Proxy and Remote Unavailable"

The problem might be that Oracle disabled directory listing and every attempt to get the content without the full GAV returns a 404 code.

How to workaround this on Nexus?

Using Nexus OS Edition 1.9.2.2

```
Configuration:

Remote Storage Location = http://download.oracle.com/maven/
Download Remote Indexes = True
Auto Blocking Active = False
File Content Validation = True
CheckSum Policy = Warn
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to proxy the oracle repos, we've merged all of that content into Central now, so you can safely remove these from your Nexus.

Comment: Are you confusing java.net repo with Oracle repo?, 
If you look for g:"com.sleepycat" a:"je" in search.maven.org (http://goo.gl/NyUH0) you can't find the artifact.

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sleepycat</groupId>
            <artifactId>je</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.10</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

The url you are using is wrong. Did you mean the java.net repo at http://download.java.net/maven/2/

Comment: No there really is content there (e.g. http://download.oracle.com/maven/com/sleepycat/je/maven-metadata.xml) but I don't think it is indexed.  You would at least need to know groupId/artifactId.

Comment: java.net is another repo, no problem with it because it is indexed.